# How can I get a "Message Signature Hash" different from "0x" after signing a message with a Safe multisig to verify contract ownership on Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, signature, gnosis-safe

As I need to modify some token information on Etherscan, I am required to verify the ownership of the contract by signing a specific message with the contract owner address.

My problem is that the contract owner address is a Safe multi-sig, and Etherscan requires a "Message Signature Hash", as described by the instructions in the link below
https://info.etherscan.com/how-to-verify-address-ownership/

[image]

I was able to use MyCrypto and WalletConnect to sign the message, however the field corresponding to the "Message Signature Hash" is "0x", which is not acceptable by Etherscan.

It is my understanding that the output from Safe corresponds to the intended behavior and I am experiencing incompatibility issues due to Etherscan expecting a signature from an EOA rather than a EIP-1271 compatible signature from a contract.

Is there any other way I can sign with the Safe so that I get a proper message signature hash as expected from Etherscan?

Comment: I'm not sure if Etherscan support EIP-1271, If not then you have to transfer ownership to EOA account.   https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/142601/how-can-i-get-a-message-signature-hash-different-from-0x-after-signing-a-mes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Etherscan has support for WalletConnect, based on [this tweet](https://twitter.com/eschnou/status/1485983864241725450), it seems that EIP-1271 is not yet supported.

The only other option I can think of, is to transfer ownership to an EOA wallet (as also mentioned by minhhn2910).